# Why does or equals break my REPL in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

If I open up a REPL with Coffeescript 1.3.3 and type:

```
y ?= 5
```

or

```
y = 5
y ||= 6
```

I get an an error that y isn't defined... For compiling the last one works, but the first still errors.. Is this expected?

Comment: Can you show the actual error messages?

Comment: Here is the actual error message:

y ?= 5

Error: In repl, the variable "y" can't be assigned with ?= because it has not been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coffee> y = 5
5
coffee> y ||= 6
Error: In repl, the variable "y" can't be assigned with ||= because it has not been defined.
```

This is because each evaluation involves separate compilation. The workaround is to access it as a property of the global object.

```
coffee> y = 5
5
coffee> global.y
5
coffee> @y
5
coffee> @y &&= 6
6
coffee> y
6
```

Comment: matyr is to correct, but to be clear, this is a known bug: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1829#issuecomment-5057522

Comment: Thanks Trevor, appreciate it.